# border and margin issue

Tags: jquery, html, css, margin

It's hard to explain without an example, So here is the example http://jsfiddle.net/dvXhP/2/

You can see that when you click on button remove, this event fires -

```
$('#button #remove').click(function() {
    $('#borderDiv').css('border','0px solid red'); 
});
```

Which is basically deletes the border around div, but look how the buttons jumps to bottom...

I realized that if you delete the #text div in the #borderDiv.. the problem will be solved (but I need to know how to fix the problem without deleting it).

I also realized that the buttons jumps to bottom equals the top-margin of the #text div,
which is weird...

So help me solve this issue please ! 
I work on big project and the example in jsfiddle is just to explain the problem.. thanks!

Comment: While @AlexandruChelariu has nailed the solution, it'd still be interesting to understand the problem. From what I can see in Firebug, the containing `borderDiv` element jumps down (pushing the buttons) when its border is removed. The text is actually positioned off the body so it stays put (ignores its container). Very intriguing.

Answer (score 7):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#button #add').click(function() {
        $('#borderDiv').css('border','1px solid red'); 
    });
    $('#button #remove').click(function() {
        $('#borderDiv').css('border','1px solid transparent'); 
    });
});​
```

Do this. You can test it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dvXhP/7/)

Comment: You might want to update your link, it still points to the version from the question